# Best practices for sending automated daily emails from web service

Tags: web-services, email

I am running a web service that currently sends confirmation emails out to new users via the gmail smtp servers. As I'm only getting a few new users each day, this hasn't been a problem.

I've recently added new features to the webapp that will require a customized message to be sent out to each user every day.  Think of this as similar to the regular messages LinkedIn sends out that give you a status report on the activity in your network. Every user's message will be different. With thousands of users, this means thousands of unique messages will be sent each day.

**Edit:** I've since found that these types of email are called "transactional or relationship messages". Spamtacular has a good [article on differentiating between marketing and transactional email](http://www.spamtacular.com/2009/12/02/when-is-transactional-mail-not-transactional-anymore/).

I don't think using gmail's smtp servers will cut it anymore, but I don't know that for sure. I don't know what gmail's maximum outgoing messages per account is (it might be 100/day), but they limit outgoing mail to 500 recipients per message. I'm not sending a single message to 500 recipients, but I'm going to be sending 1000's of customized messages with each recipient getting one per day.

I'm interested to learn any best practices for doing this (especially for Java-based webapps). Here are some of my thoughts and concerns on it:

- Should I set up my own outgoing mail server? If I do this, it seems like I'll have all sorts of other issues to worry about, such as preventing mail server abuse, monitoring bounces, allowing ways to opt-out of emails, etc. Are there any tools or services to help with this? Maybe something like OpenEMM or a services like MailChimp? But those seem focused more toward email marketing campaigns.
- I don't think I should have the webapp itself handle sending emails as it currently is for new user signups. I'm thinking I should setup a separate messaging server that can access the same backend/datastore as the webapp. Thoughts on this?
- Should I consider setting up some sort of message queueing service to help with this, such as JMS, RabbitMQ, ActiveMQ, etc.?
- Do I need to provide users a way to opt-out? Do I need to flag these as bulk messages? I don't really consider these email marketing messages, but I'm unsure what is considered appropriate or proper netiquette.

Any advice is appreciated. I'm also very interested in open source tools or web services that simplify things and could help me to ramp up as quickly as possible.

Thanks!

Comment: 1,000's of messages to one recipient?  I'm outta there!  Surely this is a typo or I'm missing something.

Comment: I have an application that sends out daily updates to me and a friend of mine(both on gmail). Shortly after it started sending these out, the application was labeled as spam, I had to go to my spam box and mark it as not spam several times before it started to go back to my inbox. I would go with letting someone else handle that for you.

Comment: @No Refunds No Returns: I think you should read it as "thousands of messages, each to a different address"

Comment: Joel and Jeff mention this sort of thing in passing in one of their recient podcasts (between #80 & 83), check out the show notes and transcript (you don't have to listen to 4 hours of their - admittedly amusing & sometimes informative - ramblings). To do with mass emailing and how to not be flagged as spam etc. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/podcasts/

Comment: @No Refunds No Returns: I guess that wasn't too clear.  Single message to a single person per day.  But thousands of people, so thousands of messages per day.

Comment: @Yuriy: Any suggestions on who or what the "someone else" should be? Did you go with someone else, or are you still using gmail?

Comment: @Binary: thanks, I'll check out those podcasts/transcripts

Comment: @Tauren: I'm still using gmail, but it is still going out to two people that both specifically marked it as not spam. Going out to a thousand people who aren't guaranteed to do so is quite different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With regard to your first question, yes, you should set up your own mail server.  Using gmail to do this might work for a while, but they are likely to shut you down in short order when they see this kind of activity.  You could sign up for a business account and use app engine to send messages.  Here's a [link](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas.html#Mail) with information about mail quotas for that service.

Regarding your second and third questions, It would be a good idea to have messages queued by the web app and sent out by a centralized service rather than having the app send out the messages on its own.

Usually I would just use a database table as a queue - the web app inserts rows for each message it wants to send.  A service/scheduled task app would grab new messages out of the table and send them off.  This gives you lots of flexibility if you want to switch mail servers later, better reliability if the mail server is down, easier diagnostics if there are problems with recipients not getting messages, and the ability to resend messages.  As for using JMS/MQ to do this - probably not necessary.  IMO a database table used as a queue would give you more flexibility here than an actualy JMS-based queue system.

As for opt outs, YES - you should give people a way to opt out.  I don't think you need to flag the messages as bulk though.

Comment: Thanks, this definitely confirms what I was thinking.

Answer (score 4):

On the architecture side of things I would definitely consider decoupling the sending of the emails from the main service via some form of asynchronous message queuing (or facsimile thereof using database as an intermediary). Another benefit of this approach is that if the SMPT server\network is down you could build in retry semantics, additionally for future scalability you could implement multiple mail senders reading from the same queue or implement sending throttling or scheduling (i.e send n messages per hour), etc etc.

Comment: Good point about making it easier to schedule and throttle. If I use GAE for sending mail, I'll certainly need to throttle it. Thanks.