# send email with web service

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, web-services

I want to ask if any one know how to send email with web service?

I mean, I have a App, and I will ask the user for one mail and a message, and I will resend that message to the email that the user said.

Thanks for your time

Comment: Start by [*reading documentation of the platform you chose to work in*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx) so you can learn and not just rely on asking. Sorry, either this is pointed out to you or this question will likely be closed with [WHAT HAVE YOU TRIED](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) and a bunch of -1s

Comment: You need to be more specific. We can help with specific problems. Start by creating a basic web service or better still WCF service. If you don't know how, google is your freind ther are many tutorials out ther for .net web services. When you get to the stage of "I tried this, but this happened when I wanted that" we can help with the web/wcf service. Then google sending an email with .net. Basic email sending is pretty easy and well documented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

firstly add following namespace

```
using System.Web.Mail;
```

and use following function

```
public string sendMail()
{
    string status = "";
    try
    {
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        mail.To.Add(txt_email.Text);

        mail.From = new MailAddress("**********@gmail.com");
        mail.Subject = "Testing";

        string Body = txt_msg.Text;
        mail.Body = Body;

        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; //Or Your SMTP Server Address


        smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential
             ("********@gmail.com", "*********");
        //Or your Smtp Email ID and Password
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        smtp.Send(mail);
        status = "Success";

    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        status = "Failure";
        Response.Write(ex.Message + "|" + ex.StackTrace);

    }
    return status;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do some server side scripting for that, that would be the solution for your issue. also you can check below answer

[Best practices for sending automated daily emails from web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2284528/best-practices-for-sending-automated-daily-emails-from-web-service?rq=1)

Comment: But how I do that, my problems is that I don't know how to make it

Answer (score 0):

Thanks I alredy have the answer.

I use the code for send email, and after that I only make a program that every minut call a web service, in that way I can select all the messages that i want to send minute a minute